# Responsive Website - Height Always 100%

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, magento-1.9

I have a responsive site and am trying to setup the background image so that the height is always 100%. The width doesn't matter so much, but there is elements at the bottom of the picture that always need to show. I can't quite get my coding right though:

CSS:

```
body.cms-home .main-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-image: url("../images/landing.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    width: auto;
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="main-container">
            </div>
```

My website is through Magneto, but I don't think that should make any different to the CSS.

What am I missing?

UPDATE: Just to confirm as it seems everyone is confused. I want my background image to always be 100% (no shorter). So if the browser is made shorter the image scales down to ensure that the full height of the image is always shown. So I guess the image size is dominated by the height of the browser.

Comment: Set `background-size:cover;background-position:fixed` to keep it in position. [This CSSTricks article](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) covers it thoroughly.

Comment: Cover won't make **bottom elements to always show**

Comment: It you want the image to be squished and to always abide to the width and height of the browser window, check out my answer and demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `vh` sizing element. It stands for `viewport height`, and it's supported in most modern browsers. Apply it to your `.main-container` element so that it is always given a full height and width of the browsers window.

```
body.cms-home .main-container {
    background-image: url("../images/landing.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Note that you may also want to give it a `position: fixed` if your page is scrollable.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/swnu0atu/)**

Comment: Hi Fizzix. I don't want the image to squish, the proportions should stay in-tact. Is that possible?

Comment: Change `background-size: 100% 100%;` to `background-size: cover;` instead then. [***Demo Here***](http://jsfiddle.net/swnu0atu/)

Comment: Thanks. That works on your demo but it's not working on my end for some reason. Trying to figure out why right now. Some other coding must be conflicting with it. Mine is still cropping it right now.

Comment: You may want to include some more code in your question then.

Comment: I will once I can figure out what's connected with it.

Comment: @itsk2015 - Keep in mind that my demo is applying the styles to the `body` element, not the `.main-container` tag.

Comment: Would that affect it? I tried turning off every style above it but it just doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Yes, having it within an element on the page compared to the body tag would definitely effect it.

Comment: Hmm, maybe that's the problem then. Moving it into the body would affect a lot of things and i'm not sure I can move it

Answer (score 2):

```
body.cms-home .main-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-image: url("../images/landing.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works in that I can see the bottom of the image. But I want the height to fill the available space (i.e. no white space beneath it)

Comment: give me the website to see

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Thank you, this works in that I can see the bottom of the image. But I want the height to fill the available space (i.e. no white space beneath it)

Comment: What happens if you apply the background to the `<html>` tag as `background-size: cover;` instead of in the `body`? That might fix any margins done by the browser.

Comment: do you mean removing the 'body.cms-home' so that it's just '.main-container', if so, that unfortunately didn't make any difference